# How to add Charts in JSReport AspNetCore Razor View

Tags: razor, .net-core, charts, report, jsreport

I have used JsReport AspNetCore razor views to generate Excel and PDF reports. So far, Generating reports with data has not been a problem. But, now I have to include a chart in every report generated.

I tried including ChartJS to show a chart but after rendering the report the chart doesn't appear in the Excel or PDF file. I Have used Chartjs to display charts in web view. It doesn't cause any problems in web view. It's just that I call ajax to get data from API after the view has loaded. When the JsReportPipeline renders it, the API doesn't get called.

How to solve this problem? To add chart in a report using razor views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because the chart pdf printing started before the chart was fully rendered.

For this case jsreport chrome-pdf recipe provides [print trigger feature](https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf#printing-triggers) which lets you postpone pdf print. To enable it from asp.net controller you can use this snipped.

```cs
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChartWithPrintTrigger()
{
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature()
        .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
        .Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
            {
                WaitForJS = true
            };
        });

    return View("Chart", new { });
}
```

and in your HTML invoke the trigger when the chart is painted

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
       ...
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            onComplete: function () {             
                window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

A full example can be found here
https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-aspnetcore

The [html-to-xlsx](https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx) recipe doesn't convert charts from the source html/js to the excel. The only way to add excel with this recipe is inserting the produced excel table into prepared xlsx template that displays chart based on the inserted table.

The documentation is [here](https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx#insert-output-into-xlsx-template) and an example [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/admin/VvaGnaE_).

Comment: Thank you for your help @JanBlaha. I managed to add the chart in PDF but still can not figure out how to add it to Excel. I am using html-to-xlsx recipe to generate Excel file. I tried adding it as a base64 string but it didn't help. Now I am trying to use xlsx recipe but I can not get it to render properly.

Comment: I updated my answer. I recommend trying to reach the desired result in plain jsreport service and then switch to the .net integration.